# Send data to Coveralls only from Travis, not when testing locally

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci, coveralls

I have an app (https://github.com/idmillington/dendry) that uses Travis CI to monitor build status. I use Istanbul to general a coverage report, and I'd like to send this to Coveralls, to generate a coverage button for the README.

All of this I can get working. But...

When I run `npm test` locally, I don't want to send coveralls the coverage data. I'm typically running `npm test` dozens of times for each commit. But when I push and Travis does its thing, I'd like Travis to update the coverage for me.

I could have something like this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul test ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
}
```

Which is fine for locally, and doesn't update Coveralls, but Travis won't update Coveralls either. Or I could do:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul test ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha && ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js < ./coverage/lcov.info",
}
```

Which is perfect for Travis, but tries to push data to Coveralls every time I run `npm test` locally.

As far as I can tell, I can't ask Travis to run something other than `npm test`.

I am unwilling to ask any potential users or contributors to remember to test using

```
$ npm run-script test-local
```

or some such, especially as running `npm test` would generate an upload error without the correct private key for coveralls.

Is there a way to get the right behavior here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer, as it turns out, was frighteningly simple. Travis does allow you to call whatever script you like as it runs, so I added this to my `.travis.yml` file:

```
script: npm run-script test-on-travis
```

so in `package.json` I could define:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
    "test-on-travis": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --report lcovonly ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js"
}
```

and everything works fine.